# Ionic App stopped working on IOS 15 (didfailprovisionalloadforframe)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ios15

Right after the splash screen fades out, the app is stuck on a blank page leaving this error in the console (ProxyWeb::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame)

Note that the same app works perfectly on all previous IOS versions. I tried to change the webview plugin version, cordova-ios, and played around with angular build process but no luck.

I suspect that the angular portion of the project does not initialize, cordova itself loads successfully but anything beyond that is just an empty blank screen.

```
package.json

{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "author": "test",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.5",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^3.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/adjust": "^5.32.1",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/base64": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/contacts": "^5.17.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^5.15.1",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-picker": "^5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-analytics": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.32.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2": "^5.25.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^5.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-review": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/market": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/preview-any-file": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/printer": "^5.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^5.23.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.9.0-dev.201908271352.8701106",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.1.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.5",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.7.8",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.8.0",
    "buffer": "^5.4.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "chroma-js": "^2.1.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.3.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.12.2",
    "console-remote-client": "^2.1.17",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-custom-config": "^5.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.6.1",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-contacts": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "0.9.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "fuse.js": "^3.4.6",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "html-to-pdfmake": "^2.1.7",
    "ionic-selectable": "^4.6.0",
    "ionic-tooltips": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "ionic4-rating": "^1.0.9",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.38.0",
    "money": "^0.2.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^7.0.1",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.2.2",
    "ngx-color": "^5.1.2",
    "ngx-pinch-zoom": "^2.3.4",
    "ngx-translate-multi-http-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-zendesk-webwidget": "^2.1.1",
    "paulstelzer-ionic-angular-toolkit": "^2.0.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.7.570",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.57",
    "pinch-zoom-js": "^2.3.4",
    "pouchdb": "^7.1.1",
    "pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite": "^2.0.7",
    "pouchdb-load": "^1.4.6",
    "pouchdb-replication-stream": "^1.2.9",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "written-number": "git+https://github.com/AliMariam/js-written-number.git",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~10.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~10.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "10.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.2.5",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/pdfjs-dist": "^2.1.3",
    "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": "^10.5.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "com-badrit-base64": "^0.2.0",
    "com.adjust.sdk": "^4.28.0",
    "cordova-android": "^9.1.0",
    "cordova-launch-review": "^3.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "^0.9.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-filepicker": "^1.1.6",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "^1.9.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-market": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-preview-any-file": "^0.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-printer": "^0.8.0",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.5",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.6.8",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.4.1",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^6.0.3",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.11.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.7"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android"
    ],
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "com-badrit-base64": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-printer": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "28.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-filepicker": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-contacts": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+",
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires photo library access to function properly.",
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires photo library access to function properly."
      },
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-preview-any-file": {},
      "cordova-launch-review": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": {},
      "cordova-plugin-market": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {
        "GMS_VERSION": "11.0.1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
        "ANDROIDX_VERSION": "1.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "com.adjust.sdk": {}
    }
  }
}


config.xml

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.Test.Test" version="3.0.110" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Test</name>
    <description>
    Projet Test
    </description>
    <author email="contact@test.com" href="http://test.com/">
    Test
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
            <application android:allowBackup="false" />
        </edit-config>
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <access launch-external="yes" origin="*" />
        <config-file parent="/manifest" target="AndroidManifest.xml" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
        </config-file>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
        <allow-intent href="*" />
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filechooser" spec="^1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^6.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" spec="^2.2.1">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" spec="^1.5.6" />
    <plugin name="com-badrit-base64" spec="^0.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.7.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^3.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="^0.9.2">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-printer" spec="^0.8.0">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="28.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepicker" spec="^1.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.4" />
    <plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="^2.7.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" spec="3.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cc.fovea.cordova.purchase" spec="10.1.1" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8101" sessionid="e23bcee4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-androidx" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter" spec="^1.1.1" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8100" sessionid="51c46f1b" />
    <plugin name="com.adjust.sdk" spec="4.28.0" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="5.0.4" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^5.1.1" />
</widget>
```

The error output I get in xcode when I run the app in a simulator:

```
    2021-09-23 18:12:39.035908+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] Apache Cordova native platform version 5.1.1 is starting.
2021-09-23 18:12:39.036109+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2021-09-23 18:12:39.048937+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] CDVWKWebViewEngine: trying to inject XHR polyfill
2021-09-23 18:12:39.519248+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] Writing analzed variants.
2021-09-23 18:12:39.671370+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2021-09-23 18:12:39.671712+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] Using Ionic WKWebView
2021-09-23 18:12:39.672171+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][console] 0.051022ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.672418+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.100017ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.674165+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] Unlimited access to network resources
2021-09-23 18:12:39.674738+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] Unlimited access to network resources
2021-09-23 18:12:39.674886+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 2.334952ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.675080+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.039101ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.676990+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 1.785994ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.681357+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 4.204035ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.683373+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][file] 1.839995ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.684051+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] CDVIonicKeyboard: resize mode 1
2021-09-23 18:12:39.688985+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][cdvionickeyboard] 5.447030ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.689196+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][socialsharing] 0.056028ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.692462+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] InAppPurchase[objc] Initialized.
2021-09-23 18:12:39.692603+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][inapppurchase] 3.260016ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.693303+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][diagnostic] 0.568032ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.696206+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][diagnostic_location] 2.771974ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.696445+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][diagnostic_bluetooth] 0.041008ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.696970+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][diagnostic_wifi] 0.110984ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.697322+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][diagnostic_camera] 0.042081ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.697699+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][diagnostic_notifications] 0.102997ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.698052+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][diagnostic_microphone] 0.061989ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.701847+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][diagnostic_contacts] 3.553033ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.702128+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][diagnostic_calendar] 0.123024ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.702345+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][diagnostic_reminders] 0.076056ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.706105+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][diagnostic_motion] 3.619909ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.706325+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][inappbrowser] 0.082016ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.706580+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][adjust] 0.102997ms
2021-09-23 18:12:39.706715+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 34.665942ms
2021-09-23 18:12:40.022337+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] Writing analzed variants.
2021-09-23 18:12:40.329014+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] InAppPurchase[objc] (before init): WARNING: Your app should be single page to use in-app-purchases. onReset is not supported.
2021-09-23 18:12:40.329447+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] IAB.close() called but it was already closed.
2021-09-23 18:12:43.404508+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] consoleRe [info] connected to server `https://console.re` channel `MyApp`
2021-09-23 18:13:10.249993+0100 MyApp[54132:2427897] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2021-09-23 18:13:10.249988+0100 MyApp[54132:2427971] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2021-09-23 18:13:10.250710+0100 MyApp[54132:2427971] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2021-09-23 18:13:10.250773+0100 MyApp[54132:2427897] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2021-09-23 18:13:10.251366+0100 MyApp[54132:2427971] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2021-09-23 18:13:10.251416+0100 MyApp[54132:2427897] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2021-09-23 18:13:10.253455+0100 MyApp[54132:2427970] ERROR: HTTP Request (OSRequestRegisterUser) must contain app_id parameter
2021-09-23 18:13:10.257150+0100 MyApp[54132:2427970] Request <OSRequestRegisterUser: 0x6000011bc630> fail result error Error Domain=OneSignalError Code=-1 "(null)" UserInfo={error=HTTP Request (OSRequestRegisterUser) must contain app_id parameter}
2021-09-23 18:13:10.257382+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] ERROR: Encountered error during push registration with OneSignal: Error Domain=OneSignalError Code=-1 "(null)" UserInfo={error=HTTP Request (OSRequestRegisterUser) must contain app_id parameter}
2021-09-23 18:13:10.257491+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] ERROR: Encountered error during email registration with OneSignal: (null)
2021-09-23 18:13:10.260321+0100 MyApp[54132:2427897] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2021-09-23 18:13:10.260512+0100 MyApp[54132:2427897] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2021-09-23 18:14:05.050294+0100 MyApp[54132:2427707] consoleRe [info] connected to server `https://console.re` channel `MyApp`
```

Comment: And we don't have any console errors after this?

Comment: @1antares1 I just updated the question and added the error dump I get.

Comment: Could you run the app on the phone/emulator and inspect the Front errors from the Browser with Safari Browser Technology Preview?

You get an option to inspect "localhost agent" (this would be the Ionic application running on the emulator or phone.

Comment: Yes I did that, but no javascript errors were logged, it's almost as the angular portion of the up doesn't initialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by a colleague, turned out a few providers (DatePipe, Location, Market, InAppBrowser) in `app.component.ts` and a router animation were causing the fuss.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    animations: [routeAnimations],
    providers: [
        DatePipe,
        Location,
        Market,
        InAppBrowser
    ]
})
```

Upon moving them to `app.module.ts` the app finally worked on IOS 15.

Comment: I just had a user report a similar problem, but I use angular1 (I know, I know), so I'm not sure how to map this solution to my codebase. Can you provide some hints on how your colleague found the problem based on your logs? I only see errors related to telephony etc, but the providers you needed to modify didn't have any reference to it.

Comment: We first started stripping the app from all and each external plugin, one by one, as a result, we ended up remove related services and providers as well until we hit the jackpot and found exactly the plugin that was causing this issue, it turned out that InAppBrowser causes this when we add it as a provider in the app.component.ts file, we instead moved it to the global scope in app.module.ts and problem solved.

Comment: Thanks for the input! In my case, it turned out to be some weird transient installation error for that particular user. Once they completely uninstalled and reinstalled the app, everything worked.